# gulp-foreach not looping over all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-print

I have a very basic usage of gulp-foreach that's failing so badly I imagine I must be doing something wrong; I'm just (for now) trying to print all files found in gulp.src. When doing this with `gulp-foreach` only a very, very small sample of the files are ever printed—about 15 out of many hundreds. When using gulp-print things work as expected.

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      foreach = require('gulp-foreach'),
      gulpPrint = require('gulp-print');

gulp.src([`../../**/*.js`].concat([]))
    .pipe(gulpPrint(path => {
        console.log(path);
    }))
    .pipe(foreach((stream, file) => {
        console.log(file.path);
        return stream;
    }))
```

The code with the `foreach` is triggered about 15 times, interleaved with the `gulpPrint`, followed by a flood of `gulpPrint` statements alone.  If I comment out the `gulpPrint` part, `foreach` prints about 15 times and then exits, and `gulpPrint` alone, as expected, floods the console with every file found, as it should.

I can just use `gulp-print`, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with `gulp-foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: `gulp-foreach` isn't really the right plugin for your use case.

`gulp-foreach` allows you to create a substream for each file and emit the results of the substream into the original stream. That means you can emit multiple files for each input file ([see this example](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-flatMap#usage)). In this regard it is very similar to the [higher-order function `flatmap`](http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/flat-map.html) in functional programming. Which is why the author of `gulp-foreach` has [recently renamed](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-flatMap/commit/c6adf542ad8c01d5e77152e22d18b6fc3f549d7c) the plugin to `gulp-flatmap`.

All you are interested in is to access each file in the stream and print its path, which makes this a case of the [higher-order function `map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). The right plugins for this are [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream) or [`gulp-tap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap) (which is what the author of `gulp-foreach` [used to recommend](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-flatMap/blob/0c8095c101ed952b4f0e56f01b40fddcbe7638fa/readme.md#this-plugin-performs-a-flatmap-but-it-is-misnamed-you-probably-want-gulp-tap)).

Now to your actual question.

As already mentioned `gulp-foreach` emits all the files from the created substream to the original stream. However you are doing nothing with the files that are written to the original stream. Node.js object streams by default have a [`highWaterMark`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options) of 16, so as soon as `gulp-foreach` has written 16 files to the original stream the buffer is full and `gulp-foreach` blocks.

In order to fix this you need to consume the files that `gulp-foreach` writes to the stream. You could simply use a dummy `.on('data')` handler for this:

```
gulp.src([`../../**/*.js`].concat([]))
  .pipe(gulpPrint(path => {
    console.log(path);
  }))
  .pipe(foreach((stream, file) => {
    console.log(file.path);
    return stream;
  }))
  .on('data', (data) => { });
```

However the usual way to do this in gulp is to let gulp consume the stream instead by simply returning the stream from the task it is created in:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src([`../../**/*.js`].concat([]))
    .pipe(gulpPrint(path => {
       console.log(path);
    }))
    .pipe(foreach((stream, file) => {
       console.log(file.path);
       return stream;
    }));
});
```

Comment: Great answer - thank you.  Is there any reason `gulpPrint` isn't as good an option as `gulp-tap`?

Comment: For your use case: no, not really. `gulp-tap` is more general in that it gives you the entire [`vinyl` file](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) which allows you to access and manipulate file contents etc. But if all you want to do is print file paths, `gulp-print` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your are not seen all the files, is  because you are not returning a promise, and the task is finishing before iterating over all the files

return the gulp.src like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
  foreac**strong text**h = require('gulp-foreach'),
  gulpPrint = require('gulp-print');

gulp.task('default', function () {
return gulp.src([`../../**/*.js`].concat([]))
    .pipe(gulpPrint(path => {
        console.log(path);
    }))
    .pipe(foreach((stream, file) => {
        console.log(file.path);
        return stream;
    }))
```

})